# python3 How to match == against multiple strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use `==` to match against multiple results.

Here is my line in question:

```
if string1.lower().rstrip() == "remove from list" or "del from list":
    do something
else:
    do something else
```

I want to match exactly "remove from list" exactly, or pass on to a different function, or match "del from list" exactly or pass on to a different function.

to add to the example, the 'pass on to different function I mentioned would be...

`if string1.lower().rstrip() == "remove from list me" or "del from list me"`

so it is important to match exacty which is why im using == instead of an alternative like 'in'

I also want to be able to expand whatever method works here to be able to match 4, 5, 6 strings as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either `in` with a list of the strings you want to match, it's `True` iff the string is equal to one of the strings in the list:

```
if string1.lower().rstrip() in ["remove from list", "del from list"]:
```

Or use `==` twice:

```
if string1.lower().rstrip() == "remove from list" or string1.lower().rstrip() == "del from list"]:
```

This, `string1.lower().rstrip() == "remove from list" or "del from list"`, will always evaluate to `True`, the `else` will never be reached, because the Boolean of a non-empty string is `True`, so it's equivalent to `string1.lower().rstrip() == "remove from list" or True`, which it always `True`.

Comment: would using...  if string1.lower().rstrip() in ["remove from list", "del from list"]: show as true if string1 was just remove?

Comment: @ProgD No, it will be True only if `string1.lower().rstrip()` is exactly equal to one of the strings in the list `["remove from list", "del from list"]`.

Comment: Instead of a list, use `in` keyword with tuple
`if string1.lower().rstrip() in ("remove from list", "del from list")`

Comment: ok thanks very much, that is the only reason I wasn't using 'in'. Thanks for clarifying, sometimes I overthink and become blind to the obvious lol

Comment: @ProgD the `in` you were thinking about is this, `string1.lower().rstrip() in "remove from list"`, it's when both operands are strings, `str in str`.

Comment: @ProgD You can mark this answer as Accepted if it helped you.